# Video keeps playing in background after closing popup

Tags: magento2, popup, modal, video

I have a button that when clicked, pops up a video content that can be played.
The problem is that if I close the popup while the video is playing, it does not stop and keeps playing in the background.

This is the code I'm using for the button and video

```
<div>
    <a id="click-me">Click Me</a>
</div>

<div id="popup-mpdal" style="display:none;">
    <div class="">
        <video id="videoplayer" controls poster='<?php echo $block->getUrl("pub/media/video/")?>whats-your-story.png'>
            <source src='<?php echo $block->getUrl("pub/media/video/")?>this-is-chris-saint-long-version.mp4' type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-mpdal'));
            $("#click-me").on('click',function(){ 
                $("#popup-mpdal").modal("openModal");
            });

        }
    );
</script>
```

**EDIT**

I have edited the code like below, but still getting the same error

```
<div>
    <a id="click-me">Click Me</a>
</div>

<div id="popup-mpdal" style="display:none;">
    <div class="">
        <video id="videoplayer" controls poster='<?php echo $block->getUrl("pub/media/video/")?>whats-your-story.png'>
            <source src='<?php echo $block->getUrl("pub/media/video/")?>this-is-chris-saint-long-version.mp4' type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                buttons: [{
                    text: 'X',
                    class: 'action-close',
                    attr: 'data-role="closeBtn"',
                    click: function () {
                        $('#videoplayer').remove();
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-mpdal'));
            $("#click-me").on('click',function(){ 
                $("#popup-mpdal").modal("openModal");
            });

        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: I recommend that you initialize the video once with the modal, and when you close the modal to delete the video element, so I did, it works

Comment: can u help me with coding im really new to this stuff

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example below, I'm initiating the video at the same time as the modal, and to stop the video I've removed the video element.

What you have to do from the **CSS** is the close button stylisation, I've removed the existing close item from **CSS**, and the close button (X) from the modal to move it to the top right.

```
<div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)"
       id="click-me"
       data-video="<?php echo /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getUrl('pub/media/video/')?>this-is-chris-saint-long-version.mp4"
       data-image="<?php echo /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getUrl('pub/media/video/')?>whats-your-story.png"
    >
        Click Me
    </a>
</div>

<div id="popup-mpdal" style="display:none;"></div>

<script>
    require(['jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'],
        function ($, modal) {
            var options = {
                    type: 'popup',
                    modalClass: 'popup-mpdal-video',
                    responsive: true,
                    innerScroll: true,
                    title: false,
                    buttons: [{
                        text: 'X',
                        class: 'action-close',
                        attr: 'data-role="closeBtn"',
                        click: function () {
                            $('#videoplayer').remove();
                            this.closeModal();
                        }
                    }]
                };

            $('#click-me').click(function () {
                var el = $(this),
                    videoModal = $('#popup-mpdal'),
                    videoSrc = el.data('video'),
                    imageSrc = el.data('image'),
                    video = '<video id="videoplayer" controls poster="' + imageSrc + '"> <source src="' + videoSrc + '" type="video/mp4"> </video>';
                videoModal.html(video);
                var popup = modal(options, videoModal);
                videoModal.modal('openModal');
            });
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: Please copy and paste my code into your **phtml** file because of you have not changed many things there.

Comment: try to take it now from me because I removed the responsive part

Comment: I think its not go inside this.clodemodal() if i put a console.log it not show

Comment: If i press the click me button it will popup the video if i close the video still play but when I click the click me button again it will stop and go to start of video

Comment: Did you copy all my code into your file and delete the old one? It works for me.

Comment: yeah I copy everything and delete all I dont know why its not go inside close method

Comment: OH I know whats happening I cant see the x I put. any slolution

Comment: I said about it in my answer :)

Comment: @stewart Does it work?

Comment: not yet @St3phan. cant I use css class to close the video like this `$('.action-close').click(function() {
                $('#videoplayer').remove();
                console.log('remove');
            });`

Comment: Check this https://goo.gl/N7w1T6 and listen to the headphones.

Comment: Please change the string "X" with "Close" from this `buttons: [{
                        text: 'X',
                        class: 'action-close',
                        attr: 'data-role="closeBtn"',
                        click: function () {
                            $('#videoplayer').remove();
                            this.closeModal();
                        }
                    }]` and click to "Close" button

Comment: thank you. do u know when I start the video it will auto play something like that

Comment: Check this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_autoplay.asp, you have in this link all attributes for video.